# T-SQL Query Help

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble getting my queries to return appropriate results for the following queries though:

1. For a given specific date list the guests that are scheduled to check out, `group`ed `by` the villa type; additionally also present their count.

The guest reservation table has the following columns with data: (`confirm_no, agent_id, g_name, g_phone)`

The reservation table has the following columns with data: `(confirm_no, credit_card_no, res_checkin_date, res_checkout_date, default_villa_type, price_plan)`.

```
SELECT g_name, default_villa_type
FROM guest_reservation, reservation
WHERE
guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
AND res_checkout_date = 24/12/2010
order by default_villa_type, g_name;

SELECT COUNT(*) as total_checking_out
FROM reservation
WHERE res_checkout_date = 24/12/2010
```

Shouldn't that query work? When I run it, I get NO errors simply no results returned (and the count is 0), and looking at my table I know there should be 2 guest names returning as they checkout that day.

Help?

Comment: well, isnt that just possible you dont have any data with this condition res_checkout_date = 24/12/2010? Can you ensure that your table is not empty and your date type is appropriate for  this res_checkout_date = 24/12/2010?

Answer (score 4):

Remember to delimit your date literals with single quotes like `'2010-12-24'` and remember that datetime fields will take into account the time.  Try something like this

```
WHERE res_checkout_date BETWEEN '2010-12-24' AND '2010-12-24 23:59:59.997'
```

or like this to get all records on the 24th of December, 2010, assuming the res_checkout_date is a datetime or smalldatetime field.

```
WHERE MONTH(res_checkout_date) = 12 AND DAY(res_checkout_date) = 24 AND YEAR(res_checkout_date) = 2010
```

Comment: You should use `2010-12-24 23:59:59.997` in your `BETWEEN` statement. `2010-12-24 23:59:59.999` will be rounded to `2010-12-25 00:00:00.000` for a datetime.

Comment: @Mikael - thx, changed in the answer; @Jon - if this worked perhaps you should mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL is reading your dates wrong. Date literals need to be formatted as string (i.e. `'24/12/2010'`, notice the single quotes), whereas your dates are represented as integers (i.e. 24 divided by 12, which is divided by 2010).

So in your code, what you're actually doing is:

```
WHERE
guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
AND res_checkout_date = 0
```

To that end, all you will need to do is wrap single quotes around your dates.

Also remember that specifying only a date assumes that you actually meant: `24/12/2010 00:00:00.000`, and if the checkout date is actually `24/12/2010 00:01:00` (i.e. one minute past midnight), it won't be included in the result. To account for all times within a single day, do this:

```
WHERE
guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
AND res_checkout_date >= '24/12/2010' AND res_checkout_date < '25/12/2010'
```

---

As a minor sidenote, I'd recommend that you use a more concise format for your dates. formatting your dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format can be confusing and introduce subtle bugs into your code if you move your database onto a server with a different default language (e.g. Moving from a server where dates are formatted `dd/mm/yyyy` to a server where dates are formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`). To avoid this, I usually use the ANSI SQL date format, which is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, and is not culture-dependent.

Comment: If you want to be really safe you should use `YYYYMMDD`. `YYYY-MM-DD` will fail with `set dateformat ydm`. The XML datetime syntax `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` is also safe.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but have you tried using DATEDIFF for the date comparison? This allows you to compare the date based on the day, and ignore the time:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, '2010-12-24', res_checkout_date) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting date in  '24/12/2010'

```
SELECT g_name, default_villa_type
FROM guest_reservation, reservation
WHERE
guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
AND convert(varchar,res_checkout_date,103) = '24/12/2010'
order by default_villa_type, g_name;
```

EDIT: I tested to put date without ' no result. When I added ' on date it showed me some results. How are you running your query?

Comment: Yes I did try that, still no change.

Comment: When I just tried using your code above AND when I tried using the ' I got the same error:

"The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value"

Comment: try changing '24/12/2010' to '12/24/2010'

Comment: BTW I hope you dont have any time values set in these dates then you should use Tahbaza's answer.

Comment: try convert(varchar,res_checkout_date,103) = '24/12/2010'

Comment: @Jon I am sorry can i ask something? Are you running the whole code together? i mean with first select part and then second select part outside and below the first one, just like you wrote the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your date in quotes. As it is now, you're doing something analagous to `where res_checkout_date = 0` (you're diving 24 by 12, which yields 2, then 2 by 2010, which truncates to 0)

Comment: When I try to put in quotes I get the error I listed above...

However it may have something to do with the fact that all the res_checkout_dates not only have a day listed in the column data they all have the exact time associated with them too, so they all list "25/12/2010 11:00:00 AM".

I think that's causing the error? So how do I incorporate that timestamp as well?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    SELECT g_name, default_villa_type
    FROM guest_reservation, reservation
    WHERE
    guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no
    AND res_checkout_date = '24/12/2010'
    order by default_villa_type, g_name;

    SELECT COUNT(*) as total_checking_out
    FROM reservation
    WHERE res_checkout_date = '24/12/2010'
```